# Multiple Models Update POST method does not work in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I've this Update `ActionResult` and It does not work as it should be because it does not get the `Id` values from `PartialView` on button click as of that on `saveChange` code breaks 
Here is my Method and Let me explain the method:
This method is receiving two models at the same time One is from the `Main View` and the second from `PartialView` and the model in `PartialView` is of type List. In case of save they work perfect but not in the case of update

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ManpowerEdit(ViewModelsManpowerEdit model, int projectId)
    {
        db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        var manpower = db.PMCManpowerRequests.Find(model.ModelManpowerRequestEdit.Id);
        int id = model.ModelManpowerRequestEdit.Id;
        manpower.ProjectId = projectId;
        manpower.JobNo = model.ModelManpowerRequestEdit.JobNo;
        manpower.RequestDate = model.ModelManpowerRequestEdit.RequestDate;
        db.Entry(manpower).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();

        foreach (var result in model.ModelManpowerRequestEditResults)
        {
            db.PMCManpowerRequestDetails.AddOrUpdate(
                new PMCManpowerRequestDetail()
                {
                    ManpowerRequestId = model.ModelManpowerRequestEdit.Id,
                    ManpowerId = result.ManpowerId,
                    Planned = result.Planned,
                    Actual = result.Actual,
                    Remarks = result.Remarks
                });
        }
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "PmcManpowerRequestDetail");
    }
```

and this is my `PartialView`

```
    @model ProjectManagementSystem.ViewModel.ViewModelsManpowerEdit

<table class="table table-responsive table-striped">
    <tr class="row">
        <th> Manpower Type</th>
        <th> Planned</th>
        <th> Actual</th>
        <th> Remarks</th>
    </tr>
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.ModelManpowerRequestEditResults.Count; i++)
    {
        <tr class="row">
            <td>
                @Html.EditorFor(m => m.ModelManpowerRequestEditResults[i].ManpowerType,
                 new { htmlAttributes = new { @readonly = "readonly", @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ModelManpowerRequestEditResults[i].Id)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.EditorFor(m => m.ModelManpowerRequestEditResults[i].Planned,
                        new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.EditorFor(m => m.ModelManpowerRequestEditResults[i].Actual,
                    new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ModelManpowerRequestEditResults[i].Remarks,
                new { type = "text", @class = "form-control" })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

and Down Here is my Main View

```
    @model ProjectManagementSystem.ViewModel.ViewModelsManpowerEdit


<style>
    h2 {
        color: #b48608;
        font-family: 'Droid serif', serif;
        font-size: 36px;
        font-weight: 400;
        font-style: italic;
        line-height: 44px;
        margin: 0 0 12px;
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>
<h2>Edit Manpower Request</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("ManpowerEdit", "PmcManpowerRequestDetail", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ModelManpowerRequestEdit.Id)
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-2"> Project Name </label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
              @Html.DropDownList("projectId", (SelectList)ViewBag.project, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ModelManpowerRequestEdit.JobNo, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(m => m.ModelManpowerRequestEdit.JobNo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control jobNo" } })
                <div id="divStatus"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ModelManpowerRequestEdit.RequestDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ModelManpowerRequestEdit.RequestDate, new { type = "text", @class = "form-control datepicker" })
            </div>
        </div>

        @Html.Partial("_ManpowerEditPartial")

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" id="Save" value="Update" class="btn btn-success" />
        </div>
```

My view models `public class ViewModelsManpowerEdit
   {
       public PmcManpowerRequestViewModel ModelManpowerRequestEdit { get; set; } 
       public List<ManpowerRequestEdit_Result> ModelManpowerRequestEditResults { get; set; } 
   }`

Comment: What do you mean _does not get the Id values_? The partial has a hidden input for `ModelManpowerRequestEditResults[i].Id` so those values will be submitted and bound (assuming `Id` is a public property and not a field)

Comment: Yes When I load the view I pass the Id's But when I post the View they appear to be as null @StephenMuecke

Comment: Then does you model contain `public int Id { get; set; }`? And you never seem to access or set the property anyway - there is no `Id= result.Id,` codein your `foreach` loop

Comment: the main issue is with these two `Id`s  `ManpowerRequestId = model.ModelManpowerRequestEdit.Id`,
                        ManpowerId = result.ManpowerId,`

Comment: and these two `ID's are coming from `PartailView`

Comment: without seeing your models its impossible to tell which classes your referring to.

Comment: Okay Let me update @StephenMuecke

Comment: Holy COW I'd to save `ManpowerId` In hidden field instead of just `Id`
@StephenMuecke

Comment: @StephenMuecke  this value is null 

 `ManpowerRequestId = model.ModelManpowerRequestEdit.Id`, and I've Even passed that with Hidden field that still gives an error

Comment: Is that `Id` a public property in your model (i.e. have a `{get; set; }?

Comment: Yes It has `public int Id { get; set; }`

@StephenMuecke

Comment: That does not make sense - you have already used `var manpower = db.PMCManpowerRequests.Find(model.ModelManpowerRequestEdit.Id);` in a previous line of code, so if it were `null` you would have thrown an exception.

Comment: Yes that is strange Even when I reach at line projectId whos value=6 but when it reaches their even that goes as null

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand. What do you mean _it goes as null_?

Comment: Okay I've changed this line of code
`var manpower = db.PMCManpowerRequests.Find(model.ModelManpowerRequestEditResults[0].ManpowerRequestId)`;
 now it goes perfect till the end but in this case `Id` is null now

Comment: Which `Id` (without seeing your models is difficult to tell which classes your referring to). And in a previous comment you seemed to imply that you replaces you hidden input for `Id` with another property.

Comment: Well let me please read my code again :(

Comment: Sorry, you have completely lost me. A previous comment said your changed it to `var manpower = db.PMCManpowerRequests.Find(model.ModelManpowerRequestEditResults[0].ManpowerReq‌​uestId)` and that worked, but you view does not generate an input for `ManpowerReq‌​uestId` so how could that work? And you still have not shown your models for `PmcManpowerRequestViewModel` and `ManpowerRequestEdit_Result`

Comment: can you add the Id's that must be in hidden field in their respected Views and PartailViews

Comment: @KhawajaAtteeq all are added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I can see after reading your comments is the Id's are null so I will suggest add the respected Id's in Hidden Fields in their respected Views and Partial Views 
For example: as you haven't provided any model all I can do is predict

```
  @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ModelManpowerRequestEditResults[i].ManpowerId)
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ModelManpowerRequestEditResults[i].Id)
 @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ModelManpowerRequestEditResults[i].ManpowerrewuestId)
```

Because you said `ManpowerId` and `Id` and `ManpowerrewuestId`

Comment: `[i]` is not accessible in main `View`

Comment: than don't give it i give it a [0] try this one

Comment: thanks its working now but if the loop has single null value it gives an error

Comment: well as you said Id's are important than this is going to happen, and do handle the null value . try to use `try catch`